# Multi target net frameworks conflicts

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, nuget-package, .net-standard

I have a Nuget package project that targets framework netcoreapp2.2. I'm trying to use it for an application that contains other projects targeting frameworks netstandard2.0;netcoreapp3.1.

This is what I currently have in the .csproj for that

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.2;netstandard2.0;netcoreapp3.1</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework) '=='netcoreapp2.2'">
( ........ )
```

In the classes I get the conflicts I'm using the conditional directive

```
##if true
```

**1.** But I'm getting compile errors because ***some of the extensions I'm using here are not available in one of the frameworks above***.

2. *[Solved]  I get this error:

   Error   CS0006  Metadata file 'C:\Users\user\source\repos\workspace\project\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\project.dll' could not be found    project.Test (netcoreapp2.2)

Is there any way I can target multiple frameworks to be able to download the NuGet package in the other projects?

Any ideas for a better approach?

Thanks

**Update:**
*Error #2 The file project.dll didn't exist. It wasn't autogenerated by rebuilding the project. Adding the file manually solved it.*

Comment: It's hard to answer this kind of question without a minimal reproducible example. I see that you have listed netstandard2.0 as one of the target frameworks. Why not target just that? The package can then be consumed in any of the other frameworks you listed.

Comment: netstandard doesn't support some of the extensions I'm using in the package. Also, if I used netstandard, I would not be able to install the nuget package into the other projects. I think I may have to change the code in the project not to use the extensions that are incompatible with netstandard.

Comment: Thanks, @AlexandruClonțea. Updated the code that wasn't compatible and was able to use netstandard2.0.